# Selenium 3.7 : geckodriver : WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException Connection Refused

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mozilla, geckodriver

Recently I upgraded to Selenium 3.7.

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public static void main (String args[]){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
    "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");      
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
  }
```

> **Included Library:**
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/guava-23.0.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/gson-2.8.2.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/libs/byte-buddy-1.7.5.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/client-combined-3.7.1.jar
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1/client-combined-3.7.1-sources.jar
>
> **System environment:**
>
> Firefox 56.0.2
>
> Java 1.8
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1
>
> selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1
>
> geckodriver - v0.19.1
>
> **Error trace log:**
>
> Usage:
>
> /usr/local/bin/geckodriver [OPTIONS] /usr/local/bin/geckodriver:
>   Unknown option --port=8970 Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:8970 [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
>   localhost/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1] failed: Connection refused (Connection
>   refused) Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time:
>   '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z' System info: host:
>   'Maggies-MacBook-Pro-2.local', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
>   os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you.

Update after trying Debanjan suggestion:

**Code:**

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println("Debug 1");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
    "/Users/maggie/Documents/ToolsQA/Libs/geckodriver");    
    System.out.println("Debug 2");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.out.println("Debug 3");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
  }
```

Include Library:

> selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar

System Environment:

> Firefox 56.0.2
>
> Java 1.8
>
> selenium-java-3.7.1
>
> selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1
>
> geckodriver 0.19.1
>
> Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6'

**Error trace log:**

> Debug 1 Debug 2 Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506106
>   (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2) on port 2198 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver
>   server to start. Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a',
>   time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z' System info: host:
>   'Maggies-MacBook-Pro-2.local', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
>   os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>     at AutomationFrameWork.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:13)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed
>   out waiting for [http://localhost:2198/status] to be available after
>   20005 ms  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>     ... 10 more

Comment: I think you are missing exe extension while setting the driver path,  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver.exe");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error **`WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8970`** can occur due to different reasons. 
More over there is a discrepency in your `Included Library` list as **`selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar`** is never a part of downloaded **`selenium-java-3.7.1.zip`**.

Try out the steps mentioned below:

- From the `Included Library` list remove all the `jars`.
- `Download` and `Add` **only `selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar`** from [**`this link`**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) or from [**`this link`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)
- Ensure that **`/etc/hosts`** on your system contains the following entry :

  ```
  1 127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
  ```
- Run `CCleaner` Tool to wipe away all the `OS` chores from your system.
- You can opt for a `System Reboot`.
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: So see now, your initial issue of `geckodriver: Unknown option --port=8970` is solved now and we are now getting `geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.19.1 1510393448083 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:11998`.

Now can you try to try to `Clean` the project from the `IDE` you are using, run the `CCleaner` and a `System Reboot` again? Update me the status.

Comment: did as you said. I got different error: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Updated error stack in Question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the same versions without any problem.

If the path to the geckodriver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
    "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
```

is correct, make sure that the geckodriver is executable for the user that execute the code:

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I manage to resolve this problem.

The error is due to the 127.0.0.1 map to localhost.com in etc/hosts. 
Edited:
127.0.0.1       localhost

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the .exe extension. Your path should be like this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
    "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: It is in macOS. There isn't the .exe extension