# Raspbian Jessie - PhantomJS unknown option

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, phantomjs, raspbian

I'm on Raspbian 8 (Jessie) and recently installed Selenium and PhantomJS (using `sudo pip install selenium` and `sudo apt-get install phantomjs` respectively). Now, when I try to run the following code in the Python interactive terminal

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

the second line eventually fails with this trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process still running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

and the `ghostdriver.log` file reads:

`Unknown option '--webdriver=46183'`

I have no idea why this is happening and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: As you are seeing `Unknown option --port=8970` seems a possible duplicate of [Selenium 3.7 webdriver Geckodriver Connection Refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219326/selenium-3-7-webdriver-geckodriver-connection-refused)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would suggest that, these questions are obviously completely different with two different web drivers/browsers.

Comment: Try to compile it from source http://phantomjs.org/download.html when I tried in the past in another ARM single board computer, the phantomjs from debian repos dindnt work for me in the first place but compiling did.